# Ag-grid is not working properly inside *ngIF

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using Ag-grid v 27.X and sometimes I need to show and hide the grid based on a condition, for this I am using something like below:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isLoaded">

      <ag-grid-angular [gridOptions]="gridOptions"  
                    (gridReady)="gridReady($event)" 
                   (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event)"
                   
                     [showCheckBoxSelection]="true"
                     ></ag-grid-angular>

    </ng-container>
```

based on some actions user does, the Grid is showing and hiding, the second time when the grid is showing, it throws below errors and grid retain previous data and not showing new data.

> maximum call stack size exceeded

and in component I have a `InitGrid()` which is called from `ngOnInit`

```
initGrid() {
    this.gridOptions.columnDefs = [columns here]
}
```

When I removed the `*ngIf`, the grid is working fine and it does not showing the error.
I searched and someone said in this way, the `ag-grid` creates a new instance each time, is there a way to destroy previous instances?

Answer (score 0):

ngOnInit is only called when the component is initialized,
so when your grid is hidden (destroyed), and then show (created) again,
your initGrid() method is not being called.

Call initGrid() from your gridReady() method instead of from  ngOnInit()